# regex to select all characters enclosed by parenthesis provided equals sign is present

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I am using the following regex to select any string enclosed by parentheses:

```
/\(([^()]+)\)/g
```

However, I would like to select only if there is an equals sign present within the string, e.g.:

(28%) - NOT selected

(A = 28%) - selected

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, you almost got it - just use `*` quantifier with the negated character class, add `=` and add another instance of `[^()]*`. Then, you may think of enhancing it by adding `=` into the first negated character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by **Look-Head** assertion that works like `if` in programming language

`\(.*(?==).*?\)`

---

The look-head is `(?=)` and you can insert what you want after `=` sign. It is a part of the regex and not a regular equal sign. So you need `(?==)` in you code. That's it.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKsppU/1)

Comment: most elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

As @Wiktor mentioned `/\(([^()]*=[^()]*)\)/g` can solve your problem,

https://regex101.com/r/0lmEcb/1

Answer (score 2):

To add to Wiktor's comment and RaR's answer, `*` will match cases like these also: `(=28%)`, `(A=)` which you might not desire. You can use `+` to make sure there are characters on either side of `=`.

```
\([^(]+=[^)]+\)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0lmEcb/2